# Create a collage of images in CSS without fixed widths or heights

Tags: tailwind-css

I have been trying to figure out, how to create a collage of images, following my design expectation.
I wanted to mention, that I am using Tailwind, because you will find css classes in my code.

My expectation (ignore the colors):

[image: my wished result]

And what I am stuck with:

[image]

So in other words, I want the parent container to be as wide as the first/main image. After achieving this, the smaller images will autosize, so don't worry about them.

My code for this Container:

```html
<div class="product-images lg:w-1/3 my-10 bg-bg_color rounded-2xl">
            <div class="flex flex-col p-4 gap-y-2 items-center">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt="">
                <div class="small-images flex gap-x-2">
                    <div><img src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt=""></div>
                    <div><img src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt=""></div>
                    <div><img src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the main image always the same width or does it vary? If it is the same, then you could just set the width of the div accordingly.

Comment: Sadly it is not always the same width, so in my example this wouldn't work.

Comment: Then you would probably need JS to get the width of the main image and adjust the div's width accordingly, since divs normally adjust their width to the content and thus, the three images at the bottom would always make it wider than the main image.

Comment: Well thanks for your tips, but I found a solution, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem!
The answer is inline block.

My source for the solution:
[Codepen snipet](https://codepen.io/simurai/pen/evgVvm)

Well now my result looks like this and I am satisfied:

[image]

And I cleaned up the css classes and divs and at the end it looks like this:

```html
<div class="inline-block p-4 bg-bg_color rounded-2xl">
                <img class="rounded-3xl" src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt="">
                <div class="small-images flex gap-x-2 mt-2" style="width: min-content; min-width: 100%">
                    <div><img class="rounded-xl" src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt=""></div>
                    <div><img class="rounded-xl" src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt=""></div>
                    <div><img class="rounded-xl" src="{{ asset('img/man.jpeg')}}" alt=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```